Meromorphic Function With One Simple Pole
Let $f : \mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be meromorphic function with singularity only at $z=1$, and the singularity is simple pole. I want to show if $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$, then there exists $N$ such that $a_n\neq 0$ for $n\geq N$. Near $z=1$ we have that
$$
f(z)=\dfrac{A}{z-1}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n(z-1)^n
$$
for some nonzero $A\in \mathbb{C}$.
I am not sure what to do if we make the above equal to $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$, how to show the statement is true.

Hint: the fact that $f(z)-A/(z-1)$ is entire tells you that the $b_n$ decay very rapidly (by the root test etc.).

$$f(z)-\frac{A}{z-1}$$
is entire function, suppose its Taylor expansion at $0$ is
$$f(z)-\frac{A}{z-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nz^n,\quad \forall z\in\mathbb C,$$
then
$$f(z)=\frac{A}{z-1}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nz^n
=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}Az^n+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nz^n
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-A+c_n)z^n,\quad |z|<1.$$
Let $a_n=-A+c_n,n\in\mathbb N$, due to
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}c_n=0,\quad A\neq0\implies 
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=-A\neq0,$$
we have that there exists $$ such that $_\neq0$ for $\geq $.
